# Font-face not working for firefox or on mobile phones?

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I've included some fonts in my css like this

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'veneer';
src: url('/fonts/Veneer_10.eot');
src: url('/fonts/Veneer_10.eot?#iefix') format ('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/fonts/Veneer_10.ttf') format ('truetype'),
     url('/fonts/Veneer_10.otf') format ('opentype');

}
```

This works fine for chrome and safari, but not for firefox or on mobiles (tested on android browser and chrome)

Anybody know why this could be?

Comment: Use `woff`or `woff2` makes compatible with major browsers. Try to convert to woff and you'll obatin more compatibility with less lines and files

Answer (score 2):

Format woff, otf try:
Example

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MyriadPro Light";
    src: url(/css/fonts/MyriadPro-Light.woff), url(/css/fonts/MyriadPro-Light.otf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;    
}
```